# Why does the inequality 0 < cos x < (sin x)/(x) < 1 hold true in the interval (-/2, /2)?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I was going through the following proof:
[image: Screenshot]

Why is the inequality given in the first line of the proof true? As cos 0 = 1, in the interval (-/2, /2), how can cos x be strictly less than 1?
Why is $cos x < \frac{sin x}{x} $?

Comment: You should go for the classic answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/72031

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The area of the green triangle is $\frac 12 |\sin x|$

The area of the section of the circle (green + red) is $\frac 12 |x|$

And the area of the larger triangle (green + red + blue) is $\frac 12 |\tan x|$

$|\sin x| \le |x| \le |\tan x|$

then with some algebra.

$1 \le \frac {x}{\sin x} \le \sec x\\
\cos x \le \frac {\sin x}{x} \le 1\\
$

Answer (score 2):

[image]
$${\displaystyle S_{\triangle OKA}<S_{sectKOA}<S_{\triangle OAL}} (1)$$ 
where $ {\displaystyle S_{sectKOA}}$ — square of sector ${\displaystyle KOA} $

$${\displaystyle S_{\triangle KOA}={\frac {1}{2}}\cdot |OA|\cdot |KH|={\frac {1}{2}}\cdot |OA|\cdot |OK|\cdot \sin x={\frac {1}{2}}\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot \sin x={\frac {\sin x}{2}}}$$
$${\displaystyle S_{sectKOA}={\frac {1}{2}}R^{2}x={\frac {x}{2}}}$$
$${\displaystyle S_{\triangle OAL}={\frac {1}{2}}\cdot |OA|\cdot |LA|={\frac {\mathrm {tg} \,x}{2}}}$$
from $\triangle OAL: |LA|={\mathrm  {tg}}\,x$

substitute in (1):

$$ {\frac  {\sin x}{2}}<{\frac  {x}{2}}<{\frac  {{\mathrm  {tg}}\,x}{2}}$$
for $ x\to 0+:\sin x>0,x>0,{\mathrm  {tg}}\,x>0:$

$ {\frac  {1}{{\mathrm  {tg}}\,x}}<{\frac  {1}{x}}<{\frac  {1}{\sin x}}$
multiply by $ \sin x$:

$ \cos x<{\frac  {\sin x}{x}}<1$

Comment: Why does your inequality at the end consider cos x to be strictly greater than 1? Isn't this false?

Comment: variable $x→0+$ but not $x=0$ (for all $x \in (0;\frac{\pi}{2})$)

Comment: Ok, understood.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid that there are all sort of things wrong with the proof you show.

You are right that for $x = 0$ we have $\cos(0) = 1$, so the inequality
$$
\cos(x) < 1
$$
certainly does not hold on the interval $\left(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Even worse, the stated inequality
$$
\cos(x) < \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1
$$
does not even make sense for $x = 0$, since the middle term is not defined.

Comment: I think the inequality is right.

Comment: Oh yes that is right. I edited my post accordingly.